# how to search a specific word in a file made by ifstream function in c++

Tags: c++, search, find, fstream

I made a c++ program which does:

1.read form file all previously recorded events
2. Add event  to the calendar
3. Remove event from the calendar
4. Search for event by name to get its description 
5. Preview all Events of a Certain day (user enter the day) Sorted

Now I want to make num 4 that I allow the user to input a name and search for that name in the file which i added an event in before.

Here is what I tried and it doesn't work for me:

```
{
    int search(void)
    fstream checkStream;
    string searchString;
    string lineOfText;
    calender o;

    cout << "Please enter a valid name to search for: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, searchString);
    checkStream.open("calender.txt", ios::in);
    for (;;)
    {
        getline(checkStream, lineOfText);
        {   if (checkStream.eof())
            cout << "ok";
    }

        if (lineOfText.find("searchString", 0) != string::npos)
        {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    cout << "Done searching..." << endl;
    checkStream.close();
}
```

the event structure

> Event Name : fcis 
>   Date : 22 / 2015
>    Time : 12 : 11 
>   Place: university 
>   Event Discription : hi hi hi hi lol no yes ----------------------------------------------------- Event Name : fcis 2 Date : 22 / 2018 Time : 9 : 20 Place: warrak Event Discription : asdaksjbdaskjdncc ssskA ------------------------------------------------------- Event Name : support - then { new line and so on} Date : 5 / 2015 Time : 9 : 30 Place: abasya Event Discription : saldasjkldh –

Comment: What is the structure of events in `calender.txt`?

Comment: Event Name : fcis
Date : 22 / 2015
Time : 12 : 11
Place: university
Event Discription : hi hi hi hi lol no yes
-----------------------------------------------------
Event Name : fcis 2
Date : 22 / 2018
Time : 9 : 20
Place: warrak
Event Discription : asdaksjbdaskjdncc ssskA
-------------------------------------------------------
Event Name : support - then { new line and so on} 
Date : 5 / 2015
Time : 9 : 30
Place: abasya
Event Discription : saldasjkldh

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for searchString as a literal string "searchString", not using the variable you read in the input from the user.

```
 if (lineOfText.find("searchString", 0) != string::npos)
```

Should be changed to

```
if (lineOfText.find(searchString, 0) != string::npos)
```

A few other things of note -

You don't need the break after the return here, it will never get executed

```
    if (lineOfText.find("searchString", 0) != string::npos)
    {
        return 1;
        break;
    }
```

Also if the searchString isn't found in your input file, the code will never stop executing, you need to break out of your for(;;;) loop when there is no more data to be read from the file.